# How to map url_alias table to node table?

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

I was trying to use some SQL to map the url_alias field to my node field on the url_alias.pid = node.nid field. However, it turns out that these are not apparently related, sometimes they are the same value and sometimes they aren't. As I'm looking through my mysql db I can see no connection between the url_alias table and the node table.

The url alias is coming from the pathauto module. I just want to create links to my resources when the titles occur in a sql query in a custom module...this seemed the easiest way to do it.

Does anyone have any idea on which fields or tables the connections occur between these two entities?

Comment: Update: the only connection I see is that the url_alias table has a field called 'source' with node/35 (for example) which does map, technically I suppose to the node table as it would be nid 35. Maybe what I need is a SQL-based way to parse node/35 so I can compare it with n.nid=35. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not related because `url_alias` table contains all the URL aliases. You can use MySQL `CONCAT` to concatenate strings (fields or string literals).

```
$results = db_query("
  SELECT 
    n.nid, n.title, 
    a.source, a.alias 
  FROM {node} n 
  LEFT JOIN {url_alias} a 
    ON CONCAT('node/', nid) = source
  ")->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $result) {
  dpm($result);
}
```