# How to join the node table with the url_alias table in a dynamic query?

Tags: database, 10

Joining the node table to the url_alias table requires CONCAT.  Here is an example of how this can be done:

```
$results = $db->query("
  SELECT 
    n.nid, n.title, 
    a.source, a.alias 
  FROM {node} n 
  LEFT JOIN {url_alias} a 
    ON CONCAT('node/', nid) = source
  ")->fetchAll();
```

The above query is taken from [How to map url_alias table to node table?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151483/how-to-map-url-alias-table-to-node-table)

How can I do the same thing with a [dynamic query](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/introduction-to-dynamic-queries#s-the-big-picture)?

My Drupal version is 10.1.5, but the answer is likely the same for Drupal 8 and 9.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "dynamic query", and which version of Drupal this is about? `db_query` is from Drupal 7 so assuming that, but "dynamic" might mean a bunch of different things in any version

Comment: I updated the question to specify Drupal 10 and I added a link to the docs for Drupal's dynamic queries.

Comment: Thanks, example here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208295/writing-a-left-join. If that doesn't do the trick please update this question with details of what you've tried and what's happening different to what you expect - otherwise we can probably close this as a duplicate

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that topic doesn't address the question here.  It does not show how to use CONCAT -- combined with a join -- in a dynamic query, so it is not of any use for joining the node table with the url_alias table.  I'm familiar with how to do joins in a dynamic query, and also familiar with how to use CONCAT in a dynamic query -- but am not familiar with how to combine the two.

Comment: Which bit of the `join` are you unable to produce with the linked post? It’s all strings so just put the `CONCAT` in the third parameter. Are you struggling to get the correct table or field alias maybe? If not it’s literally just copy-pasting everything after `ON` in your SQL version above into that 3rd param

Comment: @Clive "so just put the CONCAT in the third parameter".  Correct!  That works. I implemented it this way: `$exp = 'CONCAT(\'node/\', n.nid) = ua.source'; $query->leftJoin('url_alias', 'ua', $exp);

Comment: @Clive Go ahead and submit an answer if you like.  Or I can post an answer.  I haven't seen any example of the dynamic query syntax for CONCAT with a join anywhere else.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following dynamic query can use to join node with path_alias table: (Drupal 8/9/10)

```
 $query = \Drupal::database()->select('node', 'n');
  $query->join('path_alias', 'pa', 'CONCAT(\'/node/\', n.nid) = pa.path');
  $rst = $query->fields('pa')
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();
```

Note: In Drupal(8/9/10) path_alias table can use to get path alias maintained for node